# Mango leaves turning black

Tags: leaves, mango

I grew up my mango plant from seed 1.5 years ago, it is growing very slow, I suppose for the weather conditions.
I live in Auckland, NZ and I guess could be too cold for the plant.
Some of the leaves are turning dark and just until recently I noticed that there is a hole on the top of the stem.
Any idea of what could be happening and how to treat it?
Thank you[[image: enter image description here][1]]